# Issue while iterating lightning-tab, as expressions can't be used

Tags: lightning-web-components

I have this code where the number of tabs is equal to the length of seasons array. The scenario is I want to display the label of the tab based on some condition, something like as below:
{season.name}{season.id}

As per documentation, I can't use expressions in template file. Even a getter or a variable won't work in this case, as this is inside a loop. Do I need to to create one more property (example tabLabel) in seasons array, and using forEach method, populate it with the value so that I can use it while iterating the seasons array?

EDIT: This scenario talks about just one property. Imagine there are multiple properties. Is there any other approach?

```
<template>
    <lightning-tabset variant="scoped">
        <template for:each={seasons} for:item="season">
            <lightning-tab label={season.name} key={season.id}>
                <c-tvseason season={season}></c-tvseason>
            </lightning-tab>
        </template>
    </lightning-tabset>
</template>
```

Comment: Yes. You have to create one more property (example tabLabel) in seasons array, and using forEach method, populate it with the value so that I can use it while iterating the seasons array.

Comment: Is there any other approach?

Comment: I guess not.. I have raised an idea :( https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873A000000EC3gQAG